Sleept for 1 hour and woke up with boner
slept for about an hour or an hour and a half, and when I woke up, I went to the bathroom. I'm curious if I experienced a wet dream because i dont remember and I urinated normally afterward and didn't feel anything unusual. I'm not sure if I need to perform ghusl. How can I tell if I discharged maniy? Almost all of my boxers are multi-colored, so it's hard to see if there's any sign of maniy on them.

Bro if u had wet dream you would see stains in your underwear or bedsheets etc. And having eraction while sleeping is normal and happens to everyone.
Don't open door for shaytan with all these is this purity or did I do wudu properly etc. It starts slow then it becomes crazy.

Brother, I believe that if you think you need Ghusl or have any doubt on the validity of your purity, then its best to perform Ghusl.
